# Name of a Cycle with Additional Edges Obeying "Distance" Criterion

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Start with $C_n$, the cycle on $n$ vertices. Construct $C_n^d$ by adding additional edges between any two vertices whose distance on $C_n$ is at most $d$. The figure below demonstrates $C_8^2$. Is there a name for such a graph family?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is a specific kind of [Circulant Graph](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CirculantGraph.html), and these are well studied.

EDIT: In the terminology used on the wolfram link, your example would be $\text{Ci}_8(1,2)$, and in general you would have $C_n ^d = \text{Ci}_n(1,2, \dots ,d)$.

Answer (score 1):

In network science these are usually known as ring lattices. They are the base for the famous Watts-Strogatz random graph.